# How to match up x and y values then separate them by a comma, and have the output go to a new csv file?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have two lists, an X and a Y. I want to have those lists create a file with the values written as x,y.

Right now I can get them to write to a file, but its just individual values in each excel cell and I need it to be x,y.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import random as rd

X = []
Y = []

npts = 1000

#print (rd.random()*1000.00)

L = range(npts)

for n in L:
     x = (rd.random()*1000.00)
     X.append(x)
     y = (rd.random()*1000.00)
     Y.append(y)
    
#print X
#print Y

import numpy as np

#print min(X)
#print max(X)
#print min(Y)
#print max(Y)
#print np.mean(X)
#print np.mean(Y)

Xsub = []
Ysub = []

mxSubX = (np.mean(X) + 100)
mnSubX = (np.mean(X) - 100)
mxSubY = (np.mean(Y) + 100)
mnSubY = (np.mean(Y) - 100)

#print mxSubX
#print mnSubX
#print mxSubY
#print mnSubY

for n in X:
    if (n > mnSubX)and (n < mxSubX):
        Xsub.append(n)

#print Xsub

for n in Y:
    if (n > mnSubY)and (n < mxSubY):
        Ysub.append(n)

#print Ysub

f = open('lab4.csv','w')

for n in Xsub:
    f.write(Xsub,Xsub)

f.close()
```

Edit:

```
for n in Xsub:
    f.write(Xsub,Xsub)
```

his is my attempt at putting values from those two lists as x,y (comma as a delimiter) in the same cell in excel. It was not a good attempt. My desired output is something like:

```
>Xsub value, Ysub value
>Xsub value, Ysub value
>Xsub value, Ysub value
>Xsub value, Ysub value
```

Edit 2:
This is what ened up working:

```
f2 = open('subXY.txt','w')        
I2 = range(1000)

for i in I:
     #print (str(Xsub[i]) + ',' + str(Ysub[i]))
     f2.write(str(Xsub[i]) + ',' + str(Ysub[i]))
```

Comment: Can you explain this? `for n in Xsub:
    f.write(Xsub,Xsub)`

Comment: That's my original attempt at getting an x and a y value in a single excel cell, separated by a comma. It doesn't work (obviously, or I wouldn't be here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have created `Xsub` & `Ysub`, you can write the pair `(Xsub[i], Ysub[i])` in the file in the following way:

```py
with open('lab4.csv','w') as f:
    for x, y in zip(Xsub, Ysub):
        f.write("%s,%s\n" % (x, y))
```

Comment: This is way better than the output I was getting before, but is there a way to a set of x and ys in one cell, deliminated by a comma? like (value from XSub , value from Ysub) all in a single column.

Comment: yeah, for that while importing in excel or other code/software, change the delimiter from `,` to any other valid delimiter for example ` ` [space]